# How can multiple handlers be managed in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have to maintain multiple versions for one single lambda function.
Is there any way where this can be managed?

For example,

get_user is lambda function and if v1 lambda is being called the handler should be v1/get_user..lambda_handler and if v2 lambda is being called then the handler should be v2/get_user.

Comment: Are you using API Gateway with Lambda?

Comment: No. Directly calling lambda functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Lambda env variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html) for logic branching in the top of the handler.

But in terms of versioning you also can use [Lambda versions with aliases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/versioning-aliases.html) if you plan to support a legacy version and the same continue to develop a new version.

Comment: Lambda versioning only support one version at a time. I need to support legacy versions as well